Windows cmd: Escape percent variable with spaces in filename impossible?
In Windows command line, how can I properly escape such a filepath? One that has spaces, percents, and variables in its filename such as %cd% and %errorlevel% without expanding the variables? Is this possible?
For example, run C:\Users\the impossible %cd% filepath.exe
I've looked and tried all around for percent escaping and quote escaping. Without variables in the filename, it does work. However if the filename contains percents with variables such as %cd% or %errorlevel% nothing appears to work at all, no matter any escape sequence.
Things I have tried:
"C:\Users\the impossible %cd% filepath.exe"
"C:\Users\the impossible %%cd%% filepath.exe"
"C:\Users\the impossible ^%cd^% filepath.exe"

There is no command. I am merely trying to run the process in Windows command prompt. I am trying to run the executable "C:\Users\the impossible %cd% filepath.exe".

There is no batch file, it is simply the command. I am referring to starting Windows command prompt, and running  the executable: "C:\Users\the impossible %cd% filepath.exe"

Why did you use the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, begin your title with 'batch:', and start your question with 'In batch' then? Also, why can you not open a PowerShell Prompt to run it?

Fixed, I hope my question is now clearer.

possible duplicate. If that doesn't work for you, please elaborate

In the command line context, there are different escaping rules than in a batch file.
In command line context it's not possible to escape an percent sign, but there is a way to apparently escape it
So in your case you can use:
^"C:\Users\the^ impossible^ %cd^%^ filepath.exe^"

To be able to use the caret in the filename, the quotation marks must be escaped.
But the caret sign can not really escape the percentage sign in %cd^%
The parser tries to find a variable called cd^, if there is no such variable it simply removes the caret and the text remains untouched.
The carets before the spaces are necessary to keep the file name together.
But if such a variable exists, the command will fail:
set "cd^=FAIL"

There exists a second variant, which can escape single percent signs
for /F "tokens=1-31" %%= in ("1") do "C:\Users\the impossible %%=cd%%= filepath.exe"

A single percent sign is escaped by converting it to %%=
It works as the first percent sign simply stays where it is, but the %= expands to nothing.
In one of the batch parser phases the parser tries to expand %=cd%, but a variable can't start with a equal sign, so it's harmless.
This variant is bulletproof, no predefined variable can disrupt it.
This technique can be adapted to require only a single %= to escape a %
for /F "tokens=1-31 delims==" %%= in ("1=2=3=4=5=6=7=8=9=0=1=2=3=4=5=6=7=8=9=0=1=2=3=4=%=6=7") do (
  echo "%=cd%=cd expands to '%cd%' special chars aren't a problem &<>|"
  "C:\Users\the impossible %=cd%= filepath.exe"
)


In a command prompt window must be used in this case:
^"C:\Users\the^ impossible^ ^%cd^%^ filepath.exe^"`

The help output on running cmd /? in a command prompt window explains on last help page that a file name (or any other argument string) with a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ (or literally to interpret <>| like in a password/passphrase string) must be enclosed in ".
All characters inside an argument string enclosed in " are interpreted literally including the character ^ with exception of % (always) and of ! on enabled delayed variable expansion which is disabled by Windows default.
% is interpreted as beginning/end of an environment variable reference in a command line entered in a command prompt window (or as loop variable reference in case of a FOR loop). But in comparison to processing a command line in a batch file, something like %cd% is only replaced before execution of the command line by something different if there is really a dynamic or an environment variable with that name. Something like %UnknownVariable% in a file name string is not replaced by an empty string on execution of the command line entered in a command prompt window while on processing of the batch file %UnknownVariable% is removed from the command line before execution if there is no variable with name UnknownVariable currently defined on processing the command line.
The reasons for the difference in handling strings between two % between command prompt execution and batch file execution are simple:

It must be possible to enter a file name containing a single % which is not so unusual as many people think or a command line with multiple % like for running an image processing executable with options like width=75% height=50%. Such options can be written as width=75%% height=50%% in a batch file, i. e. the percent sign to interpret literally is escaped with on more percent sign for not interpreting it as beginning (or end) of a variable, loop (inside a FOR loop) or batch file argument string reference.
It can be expected that %Variable Name% entered by a user in a command prompt window is for referencing an existing variable. If there is no dynamic or environment variable with the name Variable Name the user has made either a typing mistake or %Variable Name% is not referencing a variable at all. The Windows Command Processor can expect on processing of a batch file that the batch file writer has not made a typing mistake. It is also very common in batch files referencing variables currently not existing on processing a command line before its execution. Think of variables defined with optional parameters not existing if the options are not used or a variable reference where on first execution of the command line the referenced variable does not yet exist but exists later on the execution of the same command line once again.

The Windows Command Processor replaces %Variable Name% always by the value of the referenced variable or by an empty string if there is no variable with name %Variable Name% on processing a batch file but replaces the variable reference only if the variable really exists on processing the command line entered in a command prompt window or passed to cmd.exe after option /C or option /K on starting it.
The help output on running set /? in a command prompt window describes also the most often used dynamic variables (not environment variables). CD is one of the dynamic variables. The string %cd% in a file name entered in a command prompt window or read from a batch file is interpreted for that reason always as reference of the dynamic variable CD.
In a batch file can be used:
"C:\Users\the impossible %%cd%% filepath.exe"

But the special escaping rule with a percent sign left to a percent sign for a literal interpretation of the second percent sign is only for batch files, not for the command prompt window (because of the batch file argument string referencing possibility).
The following line can be used neither in a command prompt window nor a batch file because of ^ inside an argument string enclosed in " is interpreted literally and not as escape character.
"C:\Users\the impossible ^%cd^% filepath.exe"

The solution is not enclosing the argument string in " by special exception from the standard syntax rules in this use case and instead escape with ^ every character like " and % and space and use:
^"C:\Users\the^ impossible^ ^%cd^%^ filepath.exe^"`


^" at the beginning instructs cmd.exe for interpreting " literally and not as the beginning of a double quoted argument string.

^ left to each space character instructs cmd.exe interpreting the space literally and not as argument string separator.

^% instructs cmd.exe interpreting the percent sign literally in this case and not as beginning/end of a variable reference of an existing variable (or in a FOR loop as loop variable reference).

^" at the end instructs cmd.exe for interpreting " literally and not as the end of a double quoted argument string.


That results in interpreting the file name string with the caret characters as escaping characters by cmd.exe as the argument string:
"C:\Users\the impossible %cd% filepath.exe"

That string is passed now to the Windows kernel library function CreateProcess whereby the surrounding " are required as CreateProcess parses this command line string also to find out which executable to run and the file name contains spaces and percent signs to interpret literally also by CreateProcess as done on first argument string being enclosed in double quotes.
